# Why does my bundled file not include all jsx files?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx

I am trying to implement reactJS with my existing asp.net application, I do not want my node_modules folder to be inside my solution.

I am new to node.js and npm so I might be doing something weird here.

I am trying to separate my node_modules, package.json, and wbpack.config.js file out from my jsx files and my entry file.

When I run webpack I do not get any errors, but the resulting js file is just an import statement.

I am using Babel and WebPack.

Is this a scope issue that my import statement can't find my StoryBox Class?

```html
.
+-- rebate_mapper
|   +-- node_modules
|   +-- package.json
|   +-- webpack.config.js
+-- smasolutions.com
|   +-- admin
|   |   +-- rebate
|   |   |   +-- App
|   |   |   |   +-- index.jsx
|   |   |   +-- bundle.js
|   |   |   +-- default.aspx
|   |   |   +-- main.js
```

webpack.config.js

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, './../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate'),
  entry: path.join(__dirname, './../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate/main.js'),
  output: {
    path: '../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, './../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate/app'),
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }]
  },


};
```

```js
import StoryBox from './index.jsx';
```

```js
/******/
(function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
  /******/ // The module cache
  /******/
  var installedModules = {};

  /******/ // The require function
  /******/
  function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

    /******/ // Check if module is in cache
    /******/
    if (installedModules[moduleId])
    /******/
      return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

    /******/ // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    /******/
    var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
      /******/
      exports: {},
      /******/
      id: moduleId,
      /******/
      loaded: false
        /******/
    };

    /******/ // Execute the module function
    /******/
    modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

    /******/ // Flag the module as loaded
    /******/
    module.loaded = true;

    /******/ // Return the exports of the module
    /******/
    return module.exports;
    /******/
  }


  /******/ // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
  /******/
  __webpack_require__.m = modules;

  /******/ // expose the module cache
  /******/
  __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

  /******/ // __webpack_public_path__
  /******/
  __webpack_require__.p = "";

  /******/ // Load entry module and return exports
  /******/
  return __webpack_require__(0);
  /******/
})
/************************************************************************/
/******/
([
  /* 0 */
  /***/
  function(module, exports) {

    import StoryBox from './index.jsx';



    /***/
  }
  /******/
]);
```

**Updated Webpack.config.js**

```js
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            include: path.join(__dirname,'./../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate'),
            
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015'),
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react')
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
   
},

};
```

Using `require.resolve()` solved the issue of babel not finding the presets.

Comment: Could you edit your question and show your directory structure? I'm a little confused by your context and output paths.

Comment: I see that it could be confusing, thanks. I have added a folder structure diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured your entry file

```
entry: path.join(__dirname, './../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate/main.js'),
```

which is great, but you have ES6 in there, and your `babel-loader` config only applies to the `/app` folder:

```
include: path.join(__dirname, './../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate/app'),
```

which means the ES6 inside `main.js` will not be processed. You probably want

```
include: path.join(__dirname, './../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate'),
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed my include to just `include: path.join(__dirname, './../smasolutions.com/admin/rebate')` which gets me further. I also needed to add `resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
   
},` but now I am not sure how to tell babel where my presets are. Any help here would be great. Without that, I'm sure I will still not get a proper bundled file. Thanks!

Comment: Using `require.resolve()` solved the issue of babel not finding the presets.